# about JD-GUI decompiler source

Tags: java, decompiler

When I decompile a project it has a lot of source like the code below:

```
  AudioRecordDialog.access$502(AudioRecordDialog.this, paramInt);
```

or like

```
LocationController.access$902(LocationController.this, f / i);
```

What does `**.access$*****` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is anonymous inner classes.
Java compiler create single class-file per single class, always.